# DropDownList not displaying correct value in DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, drop-down-menu

One column in a DataGrid has a DropDownList displaying locations but right now its only displaying the same location for each row, not the correct location.

```
    protected void PopulateDDLs(DropDownList ddlTrailerLoc)
    {
        DataSet dsTrailerLocation = DataUtils.GetAllGenSmall(Company.Current.CompanyID, "Description", "", 1, false, "Description", false, "TrailerLocationNOCODE", 0);
        if (dsTrailerLocation.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ddlTrailerLoc.DataSource = dsTrailerLocation;
            ddlTrailerLoc.DataValueField = "Description";
            ddlTrailerLoc.DataTextField = "Description";
            ddlTrailerLoc.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            ddlTrailerLoc.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("No Locations Entered", "0"));
        }
    }

protected void dgList_ItemCreated(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
DropDownList ddlTrailerLocation = e.Item.FindControl("ddlTrailerLoc") as DropDownList;

             if (ddlTrailerLocation != null)
             {
                 PopulateDDLs(ddlTrailerLocation);
             }
        }
```

You can see from the picture that is does display the location but its only displaying one location which in incorrect. How do I set the dropdownlist to display the correct location?

[image]

Comment: Where do you set the value for the `DropDownList`?  You're populating each one with potential values (and for some reason you're fetching the `DataSet` twice...), but you never set the selected value.

Comment: what do I need to change to display the correct location? I removed the DataSet from dgList_ItemCreated

Comment: What DataUtils.GetAllGenSmall is doing ? Does "Description" contains the correct locations in your Dataset ?

Comment: Yes it gets the locations

Comment: Did you tried to bind directly on the first DataTable? i.e. ddlTrailerLoc.DataSource = dsTrailerLocation.Tables[0];

Comment: setting `ddlTrailerLoc.DataSource = dsTrailerLocation.Tables[0];` still doesn't display correct location

Comment: You have to bind your DropDown control to particular data field. Best regards,

Comment: Ok so if I understand corectly, your dropdown contains all availables locations, but you want to select one of them? If so, use the "ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedValue" property, or the "ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedIndex" property.

Comment: first location in picture should say test but it is displaying Limerick which is wrong. what would do I say for SelectedValue. `ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedValue = ??`

Comment: Bind SelectedValue='<%# Bind("TrailerLocation") %>' field in page HTML as I have explained to you. Best regards,

Comment: SelectedValue is found within the html "value" property of the <option> tag, in your case this is set to "Description" from your dataset (ddlTrailerLoc.DataValueField = "Description";). As a test, simply try ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedValue = "test"; Of course "test" must be available as a location in the options of the dropDown

Comment: 'ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedValue = "test";' makes location of each row to test

Comment: Of course it does... "test" is const and it was only meant to show you the SelectedValue use... The question is now : where is stored the desired location you want in this dropdown?

Comment: I need to get location from database

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following ASP.NET `DropDownList` Binding example:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cmbCountry" runat="server" 
AppendDataBoundItems = "True"
DataSourceID="selectCountrySQL"
DataTextField="Country" 
DataValueField="Country_Code"
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("O_CountryCode") %>' >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

You have to specify binding for `DataTextField` (e.g. Country Name) and `DataValueField` (e.d. Country Code) as shown in this example.

Notice the line:

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("O_CountryCode") %>' >
```

Pertinent to your case, instead of `O_CountryCode` it should be "`Trailer Location`" field in `GridView` `DataSource`.

To populate the `DropDownList` with values you can create and bind another `DataSource` (in this example `selectCountrySQL`) like the following:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource id="selectCountrySQL" runat="server" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Country], [Country_Code] 
    FROM [Ref_Countries] 
    ORDER BY [Country]" />
```

Notice that `DropDownList` and `GridView` are bound to different `DataSources`.

Hope this may help.

Comment: Do I need to add anything to PopulateDDLS?

Comment: I have extended the answer: you can populate the DropDown in code-behind as it's done in your sample. Best regards,